Error com.android.volley.TimeoutError en Android Studio con backend en flask
tengo un problema, quiero enviar una variable a mi backend con flask desde Android studio pero me sale el error com.volley.android.TimeoutError, lo curiosos es que probe este mismo codigo con express.js y funciono correctamente, agredeceria como puedo solucionar el error.
Hice pruebas con postman y funciona correctamente.
Adjunto evidencia:

Codigo de backend en flask:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS  # Importa CORS desde flask_cors
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

# Cargar datos desde el CSV


def cargar_datos(ruta_csv):
    data = pd.read_csv(ruta_csv)
    X = data['Pregunta']
    y = data['Respuesta']
    return X, y

# Entrenar el modelo


def entrenar_modelo(X, y):
    model = make_pipeline(CountVectorizer(), MultinomialNB())
    model.fit(X, y)
    return model

# Responder preguntas


def responder_pregunta(model, pregunta):
    return model.predict([pregunta])[0]

# Ruta para procesar preguntas


@app.route('/pregunta', methods=['POST'])
def pregunta():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pregunta_json = request.json
        pregunta = pregunta_json.get('pregunta')
        if pregunta is not None:
            respuesta = responder_pregunta(model, pregunta)
            return jsonify({"respuesta": respuesta})
        else:
            return jsonify({"error": "No se proporcionó la pregunta"}), 400
    else:
        return jsonify({"error": "Método no permitido"}), 405


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ruta_csv = 'entrena.csv'  # Ruta al archivo CSV
    X, Y = cargar_datos(ruta_csv)
    model = entrenar_modelo(X, Y)
    app.run(debug=True)


Y este es el código de android studio donde envió la petición post y recibo la respuesta
private RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface;
private ArrayList<Message> messages;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private recyclerAdapter adapter;
private ImageButton sendButton;
private EditText msgInput;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chatbot);



        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        // Establece el gestor de diseño del RecyclerView.
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        // Establece una animación.
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        messages = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new recyclerAdapter(messages);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.msgButton);
        msgInput = findViewById(R.id.msgInput);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = msgInput.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!message.isEmpty()) {
                    sendMessage(message);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        // Añade el mensaje del usuario al RecyclerView.
        messages.add(new Message(true, message));
        int newPosition = messages.size() - 1;
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(newPosition);
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(newPosition);

        // Obtiene la respuesta del backend.
        getResponse(message);
    }

    public void getResponse(String message) {
        String url = "http://192.168.1.67:5000/pregunta";
        //String url_node = "http://192.168.1.67:4000/auth/pregunta";
        Log.d("Message", message);

        // Crea un objeto JSON para enviar al backend
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonBody.put("pregunta", message);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Añade la respuesta del backend al RecyclerView.
                        messages.add(new Message(false, response));
                        int newPosition = messages.size() - 1;
                        adapter.notifyItemInserted(newPosition);
                        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(newPosition);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Maneja los errores de la solicitud.
                        Toast.makeText(ChatbotActivity.this, "Error en la solicitud: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                // Convierte el objeto JSON en bytes
                return jsonBody.toString().getBytes();
            }

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }
        };

        // Añade la solicitud a la cola de solicitudes.
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

El código así como esta me funciona con express, pero no funciona con flask, e intentado conectarme con http://127.0.0.1:5000/pregunta, http://localhost:5000/pregunta, http://192.168.1.67:5000/pregunta y no funciona, agradecería sus comentarios para solucionar el error
